# UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types when add element in list

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to add element in filtered index. Here's my code, `A` is dataframe and `index` is a column

```
my_input = A["index"] + 'a.age'
ML_filtered = ML["index"].isin(my_input)
```

Here's my error message

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')
```

What's wrong with the code?

*Edit*

I try `my_input = A["index"] + 'a.age'`

The error is

`TypeError: Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class 'list'>`

Comment: What is `print (A["index"].head(3).tolist())` and  `print (ML["index"].head(3).tolist())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is list/array in column `A['index']`, possible solution is flatten it by[`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) :

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'index':[[1,2],[2,5]]}).applymap(np.array)
print (A)
    index
0  [1, 2]
1  [2, 5]

ML = pd.DataFrame({'index':['1a.age','5a.age', 'tmp']})

my_input = A["index"].explode().astype(str) + 'a.age'
ML_filtered = ML["index"].isin(my_input)
print (ML_filtered)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: index, dtype: bool
```